# Licence error and update issue cause of same plugin name / handle

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugins

We developed a plugin with the name "poll" (composer.json: webhub/poll) for one single project. Now we get the licence error in the control panel, cause there is a plugin to buy which has got the same name (https://plugins.craftcms.com/poll).

First Problem: ./craft update all wants to update our plugin: poll 0.0.1 => 1.2.5 but we really do not have a version 1.2.5.

Second Problem: at the control panel plugins page, we have our plugin listed, but with an licence-code-input-field and the error message, that we don't have a licence.

The Reason for all of this is, that we picked the wrong name for our plugin, but renaming it is a pretty dirty task. Does anyone has a got a better idea?

The composer.json looks like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator": "^1.6",
    "carlcs/craft-redactorcustomstyles": "3.0.4",
    "cavellblood/craft-string-base64": "1.0.1",
    "codemonauts/craft-instagram-feed": "1.0.5",
    "craftcms/cms": "3.5.3",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.7.0",
    "doublesecretagency/craft-matrixcolors": "2.0.1",
    "ether/seo": "3.6.6",
    "hybridinteractive/craft-position-fieldtype": "1.0.16",
    "meyfa/php-svg": "^0.9.0",
    "mildlygeeky/craft-redactor-script-buttons": "1.1.1",
    "mmikkel/cp-field-inspect": "1.2.0",
    "percipioglobal/craft-colour-swatches": "^1.2",
    "studioespresso/craft-dumper": "2.0.0",
    "topshelfcraft/environment-label": "3.2.0",
    "verbb/expanded-singles": "1.1.3",
    "verbb/super-table": "2.6.0.4",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    "webhub/poll": "0.0.1",
    "webhub/super-sticker-generator": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\laravelmixmodule\\": "modules/laravelmixmodule/src/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "./plugins/*"
    }
  ],
  "require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "^3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not gonna like this answer, but... rename your plugin. There's no way to reasonably circumvent *all* of the conflicts you're going to run into by keeping the same name as an existing public plugin.

If it's a private plugin that you're only using on a single site, consider converting it into a module instead.

Comment: Ok, we thought so as well. But how do we do that, without losing data? Renaming it in its plugin files is easy, but what about the databesshizzle?

Comment: The database impact should be minimal. At worst, maybe you manually adjust a few table names, and/or write some migrations to handle the transition.